# how to write separated by comma on reading the data in android

Tags: android

I have 3 Edit Text , one save button and one read button.

Already saving the single .txt file in sd card.

**how to save these type:** This is srinu welcome to android,7304231213,8756435453

**What I want:** click the read button separated by comma will read 3 diff edit text.
This is one edit text(This is srinu welcome to android) and another edit text in this(7304231213) and another edit text in this(8756435453).These three inside edit text will display the data.

**How to write separated by comma on reading in android.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] stringArray = string.split(",");
```

This will separate the string by comma into  a String array;

Then assign the string to corresponding EditText.

Comment: i THINK THIS CODE IS NOT WORKING

Comment: Did you try it? And what you got?

Comment: I  have this code                File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
   FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
   BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
     new InputStreamReader(fIn));
   String aDataRow = "";
   String aBuffer = "";
   while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
    aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
   }
    
                     
   smsedit.setText(aBuffer);
   myReader.close();i THINK THIS CODE IS NOT WORKING.I have this code

Comment: before one is read button this code is save buttonFile myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
   myFile.createNewFile();
   FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
   OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
   myOutWriter.append(smsedit.getText()+","+phoneNo1Edit.getText()+","+phoneNo2Edit.getText()+","+phoneNo3Edit.getText());
   myOutWriter.close();
   fOut.close();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Done SAVE 'mysdfile.txt'",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();} catch (Exception e) {
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: OK, But I think you should edit your question to post the code for better reading.  You already save the result into text file in single line. So when you read it from the file, why you append '\n' to it? aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) will hold the result from the text file if you store it as single line, try to print it out to see the value. If it is in the format a,b,c , then you can just split it into an array

Answer (score 2):

You just have to append comma after the String that you are saving into the file.
Do like this:

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_APPEND));
        out.write(StoryId + ",");    

        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

So when reading from the file your values will be separated by comma.

```
while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    buf.append(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have three Edit texts - one, two and three.
Use the following code to generate the required format

```
String result = one.getText().toString()+", "+two.getText().toString()+", "+three.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I have this code     File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
   FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
   BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
     new InputStreamReader(fIn));
   String aDataRow = "";
   String aBuffer = "";
   while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
    aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
   }
    
                     
   smsedit.setText(aBuffer);
   myReader.close();

Comment: this is the getting means save the code. I want to reading the code

Comment: You are using this code to read the contents of the file. You should add the ',' (comma) while saving the text in the file.

Comment: this code is save buttonFile myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt"); myFile.createNewFile(); FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile); OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); myOutWriter.append(smsedit.getText()+","+phoneNo1Edit.getText()+","+phoneNo2E‌​dit.getText()+","+phoneNo3Edit.getText()); myOutWriter.close(); fOut.close(); Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Done SAVE 'mysdfile.txt'",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();} catch (Exception e) { Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Replace myOutWriter.append(smsedit.getText()+","+phoneNo1Edit.getText()+","+phoneNo2E‌​d‌​it.getText()+","+phoneNo3Edit.getText());

with

myOutWriter.append(smsedit.getText().toString()+","+phoneNo1Edit.getText().toString()+","+phoneNo2E‌​d‌​it.getText().toString()+","+phoneNo3Edit.getText().toString());

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 3 Edit text as et1,et2,et3 and you have String output_string which you getting from .txt file.Format that String as

```
String[] ans=your_string.split(",");
et1.setText(ans[0]);
et2.setText(ans[1]);
et3.setText(ans[2]);
```

Make sure that the your text don't have the comma  except the separator ",".

Comment: I have this code       File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
   FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
   BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
     new InputStreamReader(fIn));
   String aDataRow = "";
   String aBuffer = "";
   while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
    aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
   }
    
                     
   smsedit.setText(aBuffer);
   myReader.close();

Comment: In above code add `String[] ans=aBuffer.split(",");`
`et1.setText(ans[0]);`
`et2.setText(ans[1]);`
`et3.setText(ans[2]);`

Comment: the above code of read data from file is working.Just check you added **Permission** for read and write into file on **SDCARD** and while reading make sure the file is exist.

Comment: its not working sir .ask same  new question put in my code .plz see the code

Comment: actually i have the same code and its working.i don't know why it is not working at your side.

Comment: plz once try sir. It is working.but this code is display reading is single edit text . I want to read is diff edit text.for example first edit test (This is srinu welcome to android)is this display read,and second edit text(7304231213)is this no reading and third edit text (8756435453) is this no is reading . plz give me This type of Reading code is I want

Comment: i am giving you code for reading one record `File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");`
 `FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);`
  `BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(fIn));`
  `String aDataRow = ""; String aBuffer = "";`
  
   `String[] ans=aDataRow.split(",");` 
    `et1.setText(ans[0]);` 
    `et2.setText(ans[1]);` 
    `et3.setText(ans[2]);`
    `myReader.close();`

Comment: that is working .you send me starting code is working I am put in wrong place .Thank you sir